# How to hide column from my database using json_encodage in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a database that I `fetch` in a `json_encode` in PHP, but I would like to hide a `column`. I have too many `column` to call in my `SQL request`, that's why I've just did a : `SELECT *`. So, I would like to hide `login` and `password` column, for example.

```
$bdd = $connect->query("
SELECT * FROM dmlog.dm LEFT JOIN dmlog.users ON users.id_user = dm.id_used
");
$rows = array();
while ($r = $bdd->fetch()) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` so you don't get two sets of each record. With this parameter passed to the fetch you will only get back an associative array, the column will be the index. You can then pass the ones you don't want into an `unset`.

```
$bdd = $connect->query('SELECT * FROM dmlog.dm LEFT JOIN dmlog.users ON users.id_user = dm.id_used');
$rows = array();
while($r = $bdd->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    unset($r["login"], $r["login_pass"], $r["login_email"]); //remove login, Login_email, and password from the return
    $rows[] = $r; 
}
echo json_encode($rows);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just unset `login` and `password` before you insert it to `$rows` array

```
while ($r = $bdd->fetch()) {
    unset($r["login"]);
    unset($r["password"]);
    $rows[] = $r;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, and if you want to know why, I've found this : https://developpaper.com/explanation-of-the-impact-of-php-unset-on-json_encode/